# Angular <option> for null not working in salesforce.com

Tags: angularjs, salesforce

In salesforce.com Visualforce pages the default option value for null is not being displayed. I have a very simple select component with one option child for the none or null value as defined by the Angular Docs (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

Here is the app:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"/>
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.colors = [
            {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
            {name:'white', shade:'light'},
            {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
            {name:'blue', shade:'dark'},
            {name:'yellow', shade:'light'}
        ];
    }
</script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <select ng-model="color" ng-options="c.name for c in colors">
            <option value="">-- choose color --</option>
        </select>   
        {{color.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see on this page, http://geopointedev-developer-edition.na14.force.com/angularoption , the "-- choose color --" option is not displayed. But on this jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/MTfRD/670/ , it is working perfectly. Any ideas why the none option is not being displayed in salesforce.com Visualforce pages?

Comment: In the sample page you have a attribute-less `<option>` tag, you need `value=""` attribute and I bet it'll work like your fiddle. I noticed when I copied your pages source over to the fiddle and it behaved the same, with no default.

Comment: Ya, I just discovered that myself. Salesforce is removing empty attributes so the value="" never renders on the page and this is breaking angular. Still not sure how to resolve. Think this is a bug/feature request for angulars where it should treat an <option> with no value the same as <option value="">

Comment: I have a couple possible temporary solutions you could possibly try, they are really long so I am going to post them in an answer.

Comment: I completely agree with you that this is a possible bug, I can't think of any reason that an empty `<option>` tag shouldn't be resolved to `<option value="">`. They may have a better explanation as to why though.